# ROS, windows10 - gazebo not launching

Tags: ubuntu, ros, gazebo-simu

I want to start my adventure with ROS and Gazebo, so far I've followed this guide http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu on windows 10 with ubuntu App and VcXsrv

I was trying to check if everything is ok by running http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim and I've got an error. I was trying to find what exactly I need to reinstall and how, but I did not any solution which worked, so far.

```
root@LAPTOP-SHF5HIA8:~# rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```